# How to Add Vesting pallet

Tags: error

```
# Clone the repo
git clone https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template
cd substrate-node-template
cargo build --release
```

Add scheduler-pallet Add this line in runtime cargo.toml

```
pallet-vesting = { default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.23" }

'pallet-vesting/std',
```

Check that the new dependencies resolve correctly by running the following command:

```
cargo check -p node-template-runtime
```

then it gives below error

```
error[E0046]: not all trait items implemented, missing: `Event`, `Currency`, `BlockNumberToBalance`, `MinVestedTransfer`, `WeightInfo`, `MAX_VESTING_SCHEDULES`
     --> /home/amit/Substrate/New Pallet/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:203:1
      |
  203 | impl pallet_vesting::Config for Runtime {}
      | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ missing `Event`, `Currency`, `BlockNumberToBalance`, `MinVestedTransfer`, `WeightInfo`, `MAX_VESTING_SCHEDULES` in implementation
      |
      = help: implement the missing item: `type Event = Type;`
      = help: implement the missing item: `type Currency = Type;`
      = help: implement the missing item: `type BlockNumberToBalance = Type;`
      = help: implement the missing item: `type MinVestedTransfer = Type;`
      = help: implement the missing item: `type WeightInfo = Type;`
      = help: implement the missing item: `const MAX_VESTING_SCHEDULES: u32 = 42;`

  For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0046`.
```

---

```
// runtime/lib.rs

parameter_types! {
    pub const MinVestedTransfer: Balance = 100 * DOLLARS;
}
impl pallet_vesting::Config for Runtime {
    type Event = Event;
    type Currency = Balances;
    type BlockNumberToBalance = ConvertInto;
    type MinVestedTransfer = MinVestedTransfer;
    type WeightInfo = pallet_vesting::weights::SubstrateWeight<Runtime>;
    // `VestingInfo` encode length is 36bytes. 28 schedules gets encoded as 1009 bytes, which is the
    // highest number of schedules that encodes less than 2^10.
    const MAX_VESTING_SCHEDULES: u32 = 28;
}
```

After add this is code in runtime/lib.rs

give below error

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `tikv-jemalloc-sys v0.4.3+5.2.1-patched.2`
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/work-with-pallets/add-a-pallet/) about how to add a pallet to runtime.

And for the error, here's an [example](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/ca570cffee47d9fa4806715b0e8b284ec6db7e65/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L1353-L1362). This is a very basic Rust question. I think you should go for some Rust knowledge first.